# How to indicate default connection to open ethereum network popup in metamask

Tags: metamask

How to make the metamask open asking for the default ethereum main connection? I put the data in my script and this error indicates that I can't call the default connection! how do you do? Thank you very much

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: May not specify default MetaMask chain. {code: -32602, message: 'May not specify default MetaMask chain.'}


const networks = {
  Ethereum: {
    chainId: `0x${Number(1).toString(8)}`,
    chainName: "Ethereum Mainnet",
    nativeCurrency: {
      name: "Ethereum Mainnet",
      symbol: "ETH",
      decimals: 18
    },
```

Comment: I used the wallet_switchEthereumChain method instead of wallet_addEthereumChain to return the default connection
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For any of the default MetaMask networks, you'll need to use `wallet_switchEthereumChain` instead of `wallet_addEthereumChain`, providing only the `chainId` in the request, like so:

```js
ethereum.request({
   method: "wallet_switchEthereumChain",
   params: [{
      chainId: "0x1"
   }]
})
```