# How to change (or prompt to change) a user's current metamask network programmatically?

Tags: solidity, metamask, contract-invocation, ethers.js, json-rpc

I made a dApp that allows users to collect token rewards on multiple different chains. For the sake of an example say it is `Rinkeby` and `Mumbai`.

In order to get signer and provider to execute my contract functions with `ethers.js` I utilise this code:

```
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider);
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
    const signer = wallet.provider.getSigner(wallet.address);
```

It gets the current provider and using a contract function allows to claim the rewards on user's current chain, `Rinkeby`. Then if the user wants to collect rewards on the other chain `Mumbai`, he has to change the network in Metamask. I want it to be done automatically when user presses `"Claim"` button.

How do I change the user's network programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer to a different question help? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120733/how-to-indicate-default-connection-to-open-ethereum-network-popup-in-metamask/129690#129690

Comment: @natewelch_ not really, the accepted answer fully solves the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code that you need to prompt a switch from the current selected network to Mumbai, using the `window.ethereum` global API injected directly by MetaMask.

```js
  // Prompt the user to switch to the Mumbai testnet

async function switchNetwork() {
   await window.ethereum.request({
   method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
   params: [{ chainId: '0x13881' }],    // chainId must be in HEX with 0x in front
   });
}
```

You can use this [converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html) to convert decimals to HEX.

> Note that this will give an error if the Network is not yet set up on MetaMask. You can check the [MetaMask docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#unrestricted-methods) to see how they recommend to handle this :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is wondering how to do this with ethers js 6, here is how to pass the correct chain id:

Example to prompt the user to switch to sepolia testnet (chain id 11155111)

```
await (window as any).ethereum.request({
  method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
  params: [{ chainId: toBeHex(11155111) }],
});
```

use `toBeHex` utility function: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/utils/#toBeHex